# Login Redirect goes to STOMP endpoint

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I have a relatively simple setup where I am using stomp over websockets to retrieve data from my backend to avoid resetting the session timeout.  I am running into an issue that mostly happens when I restart my server. I reboot and I am properly prompted to login. After the login succeeds I am redirected.  However instead of being redirected to the page I requested I am redirected to the stomp endpoint.

I suspect this is a timing issue where the stomp client is continuing to connect to the initial stomp http endpoint after the server starts up and is overwriting the request to the page with a request to the stomp endpoint.

Is there some way to make the stomp endpoint not a valid target for a login redirect?

This seems like it is really only an issue during dev since it really only occurs when the server is restarted.  However, with my dev environment being deployed on push I dont want the testers to report this as an issue.